# How to call web service method in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, web-services

As title, in Linux System,how can I call web service method in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use open source libraries like **[gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)** or **[Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/)**.

Note that this has nothing to do with the underlying platform, Web services need the data to be encapsulated in a SOAP object(in case of SOAP web service) and these libraries just provide you the framework to do so.

The above libraries use the wsdl of the web service as an input parameter and generate the necessary stubs for communication with the web service.They abstract the nitty gritty's of communication with the web service from the end user and provide simple interfaces to get and set the data to be sent or received over the web service.